How to define the Operation value equal "is" for azure WAF custom rule in Bicep?
I have try to define the azure WAF custom rule via Bicep in vs code (installed bicep plugin).
Such as
resource appGatewayFirewall 'Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies@2022-09-01' = {
  name: firewallName
  location: location
  properties: {
    customRules: [
      {
        name: 'grafanaazuremonitordatasource'
        action: 'Allow'
        priority: 15
        ruleType: 'MatchRule'
        matchConditions: [

          { 
            matchVariables: [
              {
                variableName: 'RequestUri'
              }
            ]
          
            operator: 'Contains'   
            negationConditon: true
            matchValues: [
             '/api/ds/query?ds_type=grafana-azure-monitor-datasource'
            ]           
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
    policySettings: {
      requestBodyCheck: true
      maxRequestBodySizeInKb: 128
      fileUploadLimitInMb: 100
      state: 'Enabled'
      mode: 'Prevention'
    }
    managedRules: {
      managedRuleSets: [
        {
          ruleSetType: 'OWASP'
          ruleSetVersion: '3.2'
          ruleGroupOverrides: [
            // If necessary and safe, you can disable necessary rules. e.g. like this
            // {
            //   ruleGroupName: 'REQUEST-913-SCANNER-DETECTION'
            //   rules: [
            //     {
            //       ruleId: '913100'
            //       state: 'Disabled'
            //       action: 'AnomalyScoring'
            //     }
            //   ]
            // }
          ]
        }
      ]
      exclusions: [
        // If necessary and safe, you can disable checking specific arguments or parameters. e.g. like this:
        // {
        //   "matchVariable": "RequestArgNames",
        //   "selectorMatchOperator": "Equals",
        //   "selector": "repairForm"
        // }
      ]
    }
  }
}

In the matchConditions block,there is no parameter to define the Operation value "is" or "is not" according following image.
After I deploy the Bicep script successfully, the Operation value is "is not",in fact I hope it is "is". I dont know how to define this parameter name or format.
Thanks.

I have looked for the method in google,but failed.

Azure WAF supports various operators such as Equals, Contains, StartsWith, EndsWith, etc., each suitable for different types of matching logic.
To set the operation to "is", which means an exact match, you would typically use the Equals operator in your Bicep template.
resource appGatewayFirewall 'Microsoft.Network/ApplicationGatewayWebApplicationFirewallPolicies@2022-09-01' = {
  name: firewallName
  location: location
  properties: {
    customRules: [
      {
        name: 'grafanaazuremonitordatasource'
        action: 'Allow'
        priority: 15
        ruleType: 'MatchRule'
        matchConditions: [
          {
            matchVariables: [
              {
                variableName: 'RequestUri'
              }
            ]
            operator: 'Equals' // Use 'Equals' for an exact match
            negationConditon: false // Set to false for "is"
            matchValues: [
              '/api/ds/query?ds_type=grafana-azure-monitor-datasource'
            ]           
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
...


operator: 'Equal' // Use 'Equal' for an exact match,without s letter. And thanks a ton.

I see the key point is negationCondition parameter false.
[Microsoft Doc][1]
According to my test,it seems that:
And operator: 'Equals' should be operator: 'Equal',without s letter.
If used 'operator: 'Contains'',the matchValues could be multi items.
    customRules: [
  {
    name: 'grafanaazuremonitordatasource'
    state: 'Enabled'                  // Turn this rule on/off. Custom rules are enabled by default.
    action: 'Allow'
    priority: 15
    ruleType: 'MatchRule'
    matchConditions: [
      { 
        matchVariables: [
          {
            variableName: 'RequestUri'
          }
        ]          
        operator: 'Contains'   
        negationConditon: false       // Set to false for "is"
        matchValues: [
         '/api/ds/query?ds_type=grafana-azure-monitor-datasource'
         '/api/v1/eval'
        ]           
      }
    ]
  }

FYI: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/custom-waf-rules-overview
